# Spark UI for Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How to access *Spark UI* for **pyspark** jobs?
I am trying to login to (localhost:4040) for track my jobs but not load although when open spark- shell, but when open pyspark it is not login

Comment: 4041 may be....

Answer (score 1):

Spark UI available only for the time when your spark session is present. Also spark looks for ports starting from 4040 and iterates if it cannot use that port. If you are starting spark shell, it will  mention in the beginning, the port it is using for spark UI.

Answer (score 1):

Spark UI provides a realtime view for your spark job and if your job terminates you lose that view in order to preserve that view you have to add a blocking code at the end of your Spark job like `input()`and as Relic16 said Spark starts from port 4040 and if it was occupied it tries port 4041 and so on. also if you look at logs carefully Spark mentions the ip and port in the logs

Answer (score 0):

use `sparkContext.uiWebUrl` to get the URL, where `sparkContext` is an instance of `SparkContext`